# OAuth 1.0のsignatureの生成の仕方がわからない

Tags: python, oauth

OAuthのsignatureをライブラリを使用しないで、生成したいのですが、おそらく間違っており、headesの`oauth_token`にconsumer_secretを設定するのが正しいのかがわかりません。

signatureは`oauth`系の値を`&`で結合して、`SHA1`でハッシュ値に変換みたいな流れだと思っています。

どこがまちがえているのでしょうか？

### エラー

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized

"code": 32,
"message": "Could not authenticate you."
```

```py
import calendar
import time
import uuid
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import hmac
import hashlib

def getSignature(values):
  values = list(map(lambda x: urllib.parse.quote(x), values))
  joinedValue = "&".join(values).encode("utf-8")
  signature = hmac.new(joinedValue, None, hashlib.sha1).hexdigest()
  return signature

request_token_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
http_method = "POST"
consumer_key = "FakeConsumerKey"
consumer_secret = "FakeConsumerSecretKey"
nonce = str(uuid.uuid4()) # Only ASCII
signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1"
timestamp = str(calendar.timegm(time.gmtime()))
version = "1.0"

valueForSignature = [
  http_method,
  request_token_url,
  consumer_key,
  consumer_secret,
  nonce,
]

signature = getSignature(valueForSignature)

callbackURL = "https://localhost:8000"

headers = {
  "oauth_nonce": nonce,
  "oauth_callback": callbackURL,
  "oauth_signature_method": signature_method,
  "oauth_timestamp": timestamp,
  "oauth_consumer_key": consumer_key,
  "oauth_signature": signature,
  "oauth_version": version,
}

values = [f"{key}=\"{urllib.parse.quote(value)}\"" for key, value in headers.items()]

authorization = ",".join(values)
authorization = f"OAuth {authorization}"

params = {
  "oauth_callback": callbackURL,
}

req = urllib.request.Request('{}?{}'.format(request_token_url, urllib.parse.urlencode(params)))
req.add_header("Authorization", authorization)

print(authorization)

with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as res:
  data = res.read().decode('utf-8')
  print(data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

間違っているのは `joinedValue` を作るときリクエストパラメータが足りない・正規化していないことと、 HMAC-SHA1 に署名キーを渡していないところです。

OAuth 1.0 の署名は以下の手順で作成します。

1. 署名ベース文字列を作成する

   1. 正規化済みパラメータ文字列を作成する

      1. すべての HTTP リクエストパラメータと `oauth_*` パラメータを収集する
      2. すべてのキーと値をパーセントエンコードする
      3. （エンコード後の）キーのアルファベット昇順でキー・値ペアを並べ替える
      4. 各ペアについてキーと値を `=` で結合する
      5. それらを順に `&` で結合したものを署名ベース文字列とする
   2. ベース URL を作成する

      1. リクエスト URL からクエリ文字列とフラグメントを取り除いたものをベース URL とする
   3. 大文字の HTTP メソッド名と、ベース URL をパーセントエンコードしたものと、正規化済みパラメータ文字列をパーセントエンコードしたものを、この順で `&` で結合したものを署名ベース文字列とする
2. 署名キーを作成する

   1. コンシューマーシクレットをパーセントエンコードしたものと、 OAuth トークンシークレットをパーセントエンコードしたものを、この順で `&` で結合したものを署名キーとする
3. 署名キーをキーに、署名ベース文字列をメッセージにして HMAC-SHA1 を計算する
4. 計算結果のバイナリ文字列を Base64 エンコードしたものを署名とする

実例を交えた正確な説明は[RFC5849（日本語訳）](https://openid-foundation-japan.github.io/rfc5849.ja.html#anchor6)を参照してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。いろいろ勘違いしていたようです。一応うまくいったものを別で載せておきます。

Answer (score 1):

うまくいったコードを載せておきます。

```py
import time, uuid
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import hmac, hashlib, base64

consumerKey = "FakeConsumerKey"
consumerSecretKey = "FakeSecretConsumerKey"
requestTokenURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
httpMethod = "POST"
oauthVersion = "1.0"
signatureMethod = "HMAC-SHA1"
nonce = str(uuid.uuid4())
timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
accessTokenSecret = "" # ここは空で良い

def encodeURL(value):
  # Oauth1.0で許可されている文字列(許可されている文字は変換されない)
  # https://developer.twitter.com/ja/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/percent-encoding-parameters
  return urllib.parse.quote(value, safe="-._~")

def getParameterString(parameters):
  encodedValues = dict([(encodeURL(key), encodeURL(value)) for key, value in parameters.items()])
  sortedValues = dict(sorted(encodedValues.items()))
  eachJoinedValues = list([f"{key}={value}" for key, value in sortedValues.items()])
  joinedValue = "&".join(eachJoinedValues)
  return joinedValue

oauth_params = {
  "oauth_consumer_key": consumerKey,
  "oauth_nonce": nonce,
  "oauth_signature_method": signatureMethod,
  "oauth_timestamp": timestamp,
  "oauth_version": oauthVersion,
}

parameterString = getParameterString(oauth_params)

parameters = [
  httpMethod,
  requestTokenURL,
  parameterString,
]

def getBaseString(parameters):
  encodedValues = list([encodeURL(parameter) for parameter in parameters])
  joinedValue = "&".join(encodedValues)
  return joinedValue

baseString = getBaseString(parameters)

key = f"{encodeURL(consumerSecretKey)}&{encodeURL(accessTokenSecret)}"

def getSignature(key, message):
  hashedValue = hmac.new(key.encode(), message.encode(), hashlib.sha1).digest()
  signature = base64.b64encode(hashedValue).decode()
  return signature

signature = getSignature(key, baseString)

oauthValues = {
  "oauth_consumer_key": consumerKey,
  "oauth_nonce": nonce,
  "oauth_signature": signature,
  "oauth_signature_method": signatureMethod,
  "oauth_timestamp": timestamp,
  "oauth_version": oauthVersion,
}

joinedOauthValus = list([f"{encodeURL(key)}=\"{encodeURL(value)}\"" for key, value in oauthValues.items()])
oauth = ",".join(joinedOauthValus)
authorization = f"OAuth {oauth}"

request = urllib.request.Request(requestTokenURL, method=httpMethod)
request.add_header("Authorization", authorization)

with urllib.request.urlopen(request) as response:
  data = response.read().decode()
  values = data.split("&")
  oauth_token = values[0].split("=")[1]
  url = f"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token={oauth_token}"
  print(url)
```